# Message=ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.9

I was making an program to **scrape** intershala which find internships but the python program showed a error

```
Message=ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

**

in the program (i am trying to print the company name here)

```
#scraping intershala
import requests
import json
import parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = requests.get('https://internshala.com/internships/game%20development-internship').text

soup= BeautifulSoup (html_text,'lxml')

jobs=soup.find_all('div', class_="internship_list_container")

company_name= soup.find_all('div', class_="heading_4_5 profile").text
print(company_name)
```

in line

```
company_name= soup.find_all('div', class_="heading_4_5 profile").text
```

despite of having text in the tags

```
<div class="heading_4_5 profile"> <a href="/internship/detail/internship-at-internshala1632288894">Internshala Student Partner</a> </div>,
```

in this case intershala student partner

**please help me in this**

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

You are operating on an object, not on a single element, so you wont get any text information.

#### How to fix?

You have to loop over your object to get the text of each element:

```
company_name= [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.find_all('div', class_="heading_4_5 profile")]
```

Using `get_text(strip=True)` you can rid of the `whitespace` or `\n`

#### Output

```
['Internshala Student Partner', 'Unity Game Development', 'Unity Development', 'Unity 3D Development', 'Unity Development', 'Training - Roblox', 'Teaching (Game Development)', 'Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Virtual Reality', 'Game Development (Unity)', 'Virtual Reality', 'Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Unity Application Development', 'Teaching (Technical)', 'Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Game Development (Unity & C#)', 'VR Development', 'Web Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Augmented Reality Development', 'Unity Development', 'Game Development', 'Unity Development/Game Development', 'Unity Development', 'Teaching Game Development Unity 3D', 'Unity Development', 'Unity Game Programming', 'Unity Game Development', 'Game Development (Android App)', 'Game Development', 'Game Development', 'Browser Based Game Development (React/Firebase)', 'Unity Development', 'Game Development', 'Unity Development', 'Unity Development']
```

#### Note

If you like too iterate over all the listings, it would be better to start this way:

```
data = {}

for listing in soup.select('div.individual_internship'):

    listingId= listing.get('id').split('_')[-1]
    companyName= listing.find('div', class_="heading_4_5 profile").get_text(strip=True)
    listingDetails= listing.select_one('div.heading_4_5.profile a')['href']
    
    data[listingId]={
        'companyName':companyName,
        'listingDetails':listingDetails
    }
    
data
```

#### Output

```
{'1468775': {'companyName': 'Internshala Student Partner',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/internship-at-internshala1632288894'},
 '1478073': {'companyName': 'Unity Game Development',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/unity-game-development-work-from-home-job-internship-at-beyondoo-games1632755237'},
 '1479259': {'companyName': 'Unity Development',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/unity-development-work-from-home-job-internship-at-monkhub1632821777'},
 '1477799': {'companyName': 'Unity 3D Development',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/unity-3d-development-internship-in-gurgaon-at-gesture-research1632746127'},
 '1477364': {'companyName': 'Unity Development',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/unity-development-work-from-home-job-internship-at-westvindh1632819732'},
 '1477467': {'companyName': 'Training - Roblox',
  'listingDetails': '/internship/detail/training-roblox-work-from-home-job-internship-at-camp-k121632817494'},
 '1477493': {'companyName': 'Teaching (Game Development)',
...
}
```